# Password on Keyring ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, password, gnome-keyring

I have changed my settings to *not use a password* for my account.

I can log in okay, but I can't perform any updates. Every time I try, it asks me for a password **which I no longer have**.

There are two more questions:

1. Is it possible to make *gnome-keyring* not appear when there is no password?
2. What is the original password to unlock gnome-keyring on the live DVD / USB? I find it annoying on test environments when I do not know the password

Comment: Please rephrase your question. In it's current form, your question is totally non-understandable.

Comment: Did you set a *blank* password?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying your password is now set to nothing, so on the login screen you do not enter a password, but when you try to update Ubuntu it is still asking you for a password and leaving it blank does not work?

If this IS the case, I would suggest you first try your old password and see that still works here.

I am still new, so this is just a guess... But I am pretty sure that when you first install Ubuntu it has you type in a username and password. You still need that password to do things that require administrative (root?) permissions even if you set your login password to nothing.

This might help you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html